# How to Concatenate an Excel File Using a DataTable?

Tags: c#, epplus

I have a DataTable being generated using the C# NI DAQmx code. I want to take this DataTable and put it in an excel file when a CheckBox is checked. The DAQmx code records this data 'x' number of samples at a time. When this number is high, the program is slow, but it still works. I want to record a low number of samples at a time, and then save that data into an excel file.

In my current code, the data in the excel file is constantly overwritten. This is not desirable, as I need all recorded data.

Currently the data will actively record when the box is checked, but it will not concatenate. I have tried many searches and explored many methods for this, but I haven't quite been able to adapt anything for my needs.

Relevant code will be included below. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Note: Data does not have to be a .xlsx file. It can be a .csv

This code is the DataTable generation via DAQmx:

```
    private void DataToDataTable(AnalogWaveform<double>[] sourceArray, ref DataTable dataTable)
    {
        // Iterate over channels
        int currentLineIndex = 0;
        string test = currentLineIndex.ToString();

        foreach (AnalogWaveform<double> waveform in sourceArray)
        {
            for (int sample = 0; sample < waveform.Samples.Count; ++sample)
            {
                if (sample == 50)
                    break;

                dataTable.Rows[sample][currentLineIndex] = waveform.Samples[sample].Value;
            }
            currentLineIndex++;       
        }
    }

    public void InitializeDataTable(AIChannelCollection channelCollection, ref DataTable data)
    {
        int numOfChannels = channelCollection.Count;
        data.Rows.Clear();
        data.Columns.Clear();
        dataColumn = new DataColumn[numOfChannels];
        int numOfRows = 50;

        for (int currentChannelIndex = 0; currentChannelIndex < numOfChannels; currentChannelIndex++)
        {
            dataColumn[currentChannelIndex] = new DataColumn()
            {
                DataType = typeof(double),
                ColumnName = channelCollection[currentChannelIndex].PhysicalName
            };
        }

        data.Columns.AddRange(dataColumn);

        for (int currentDataIndex = 0; currentDataIndex < numOfRows ; currentDataIndex++) 
        {
            object[] rowArr = new object[numOfChannels];
            data.Rows.Add(rowArr);
        }
    }
```

This is my current method of saving to an Excel file:

```
        private void Excel_cap_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                   int i = 0;
        for (excel_cap.Checked = true; excel_cap.Checked == true; i ++) {

            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName);
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
                }

                File.AppendAllText(filename_box.Text, sb.ToString());

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned it does not have to be Excel, it could be a CSV, then you can use your CSV code but change the `File.WriteAllText` line to [File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx) which will append the text rather than replacing the existing file.  `AppendAllText` will create the file if it doesn't exist.

```
File.AppendAllText("test.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: This is very helpful. However, could you take a look at my edit for my current code? I added in your change and it will append the file upon check box change. I want the file to constantly be appended with new information as long as the 'excel_cap.Checked = true' . I know this is an amateur question, but any idea how I might solve this?

Comment: @ScottMyers - I did look at the code and I think I follow your new question, but on SO, if you need help with another part/a second question, you need to post a new question.  To help point you in the right direction, it sounds like you have a producer/consumer type of problem.  You should consider maybe looking into the ConcurrentQueue and maybe keeping the file open and just appending while you have data in the queue, without knowing more about the problem though it is hard to give an answer.

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you. Sorry for the rookie mistake. I appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using EPPlus? This `CreateExcelFile` looks like it is [a copied code snippet](http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm).

With EPPlus, this would be as easy as

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"a.xslx")))
{
    if (!package.Workbook.Worksheets.Any())
        package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet");
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
    var appendRow = (sheet.Dimension?.Rows ?? 0) + 1;
    sheet.Cells[appendRow, 1].LoadFromDataTable(new DataTable(), false);
    package.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"a.xslx"));
}
```

It looks like you have some objects, then convert them to `DataTable` and then write them to Excel/CSV. If you skip the to DataTable conversion, you'll speed things up. EPPlus has `LoadFromCollection` which may just work with your `AnalogWaveform<double>`.

Shameless advertisement: I got these snippets from my [blog post about EPPlus](http://pongit.be/nuget/epplus/create-xlsx-excel-with-epplus-csharp-import/).

Comment: I probably could have tagged this better. You are correct, that is where that code snippet came from. I originally intended to use EPPlus but couldn't adapt it properly. I am getting an error with your code, around the 'LoadFromDataTable' part. It says 'no overload for method' and 'takes 1 argument'. Any ideas why? Also, would this work with two columns of data?

Comment: Missed second parameter: `bool PrintHeaders`

Comment: The line (' var appendRow = sheet.Dimension.Rows + 1; ') is throwing me a ('NullReferenceException') error now. Specifically ('OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.Dimension.get returned null.')  Do you know how to resolve that?

Comment: `var appendRow = (sheet.Dimension?.Rows ?? 0) + 1;`. If you want to continue with programming, knowing how to debug errors is quite important.   Use breakpoints, write Unit Tests etc. In this case, the Xml comment for Dimension is _Dimension address for the worksheet. Top left cell to Bottom right. If the worksheet has no cells, null is returned_